# Porting cryptography APIs from Windows 8 to Win RT

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, cryptography

I'm trying to port code written in C# for Windows 8 to WinRT. The code uses Cryptography APIs that are in the System.Security.Cryptography namespace such as AesManaged, CryptoStream, and Rfc2898DerivedBytes.

As far as I can tell, these do not seem to be available on Windows RT? I found the API documentation(here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211377.aspx) and it lists a System.Security.Cryptography namespace but it doesn't include these classes. Are there equivalents/are they available under a different namespace maybe? Any advice for how to port this code if it is at all possible if the APIs are not available?

Thanks,
Ahmad

Comment: Can you be more specific? There are quite a few cryptography classes in WinRT, and while they may not be exactly the same, identical functionality may exist.

Comment: Well, the CryptoStream class for example. It takes another stream and an Encryptor or Decryptor and works on it. Or Rfc2898DerivedBytes which takes a password, an init vector, and creates a key.

Comment: Have you tried the `CryptographicEngine.Encrypt` method with a buffer, instead of a stream?

Comment: I have looked at that a little bit, but I'm worried about the overall package since there are several classes in use from the Windows 8 namespace that I haven't found a parallel of in WinRT(Rfc2898DerivedBytes, ICryptoTransform, AesManaged, among probably others).

Comment: Do you have a specific piece of code you can't get to work? Your question doesn't have a single or short answer. RFC2898 can be made to work -- if you search on the internet and even stack overflow, others have gotten it to work. AES is definitely available. Etc.

Comment: My apologies. I was really hoping that I may have missed an assembly or namespace or something that all the classes translate to rather than having to port each individual class and make sure it works like the original. If I have to do the later it greatly increases the risk and time estimate for the project.

Comment: You didn't miss an assembly or namespace. The APIs are just different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While some uses of .NET 4.5 Cryptography APIs can be relatively straightforward to convert to a WinRT model, many will require modification. There are a number of reasonable examples available depending on the situation that you require already published on various internet sites. Things like `CryptoStream` may need to be changed for example into using `IBuffer`s.

The RFC2898 for example may need to be changed to use a `KeyDerivationAlgorithmProvider` of type `KeyDerivationAlgorithmNames.Pbkdf2Sha256`.

It seems like the first releases of the WinRT are about building a "core" that is comprehensive and that more convenient APIs for using some of this functionality will come later or be provided by third parties.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation and feedback.